# Record on iPhone and export video with iPad resolution?(video example)

Tags: ios, app-store, preview, app-preview

For iOS app store app previews, is there a way that I can record on an iPhone and export the footage as the iPad resolution/ratio too? I don't want to modify the iPhone footage for the iPad in any way.

The gif below shows exactly what I want.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible because these are two completely different resolutions. Except having not the devices, why would it be a problem to record two app previews?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to is because I don't think that iPhones should have a different experience than those with iPads and I want them to be the same screenshots with the same video is all.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a way to change the resolution coming from the iPhone to achieve what you want, but if you don't have an iPad available, you can record a portion of your screen using Quicktime and record the iPad simulator.

Comment: I want the footage to be perfectly in sync between the iPhone and iPad app preview. Is there a way of doing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: not without zooming in and cutting some of the video. You're essentially asking to record in two resolutions at once - that's not going to happen. You will either have to edit the iPhone video to fit or record a separate video.

Comment: Okay, I am glad I know that now. I found a different approach where I will record with the iPad resolution without the UI(because that is what scales)and then crop the iPad to fit the iPhone. Thank you so much though for informing me about this and replying.